# failed to update column value via thrift api

Tags: c#, insert, cassandra, thrift

This test case will pass at the first time, but will be failed next. I don't know why it didn't update the column value to "value1" after execute insert method at the second time.

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {

        client.set_keyspace(KEYSPACE);

        byte[] key = utf8Encoding.GetBytes("123456789");

        ColumnParent parent = new ColumnParent();
        parent.Column_family = "Users";

        Column column = new Column();
        column.Name = utf8Encoding.GetBytes("columnname1");
        column.Timestamp = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
        column.Value = utf8Encoding.GetBytes("value1");

        // insert
        client.insert(key, parent, column, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);

        ColumnPath path = new ColumnPath();
        path.Column_family = "Users";
        path.Column = utf8Encoding.GetBytes("columnname1");

        // search
        ColumnOrSuperColumn returnedColumn = client.get(key, path, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
        Assert.AreEqual("value1", utf8Encoding.GetString(returnedColumn.Column.Value));

        // update
        column.Timestamp = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
        column.Value = utf8Encoding.GetBytes("value2");
        client.insert(key, parent, column, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);

        returnedColumn = client.get(key, path, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
        Assert.AreEqual("value2", utf8Encoding.GetString(returnedColumn.Column.Value));
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are calling that twice in a row in code you need to make sure your time stamp is incrementing. Use microsecond resolution and make a function which remembers the last time returned and adds one if the next time would be less then or equal to the last time returned.

Only using millisecond resolution all the time stamps are probably the same, so Cassandra reverts to comparing bytes, so value2 wins.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I used private static readonly DateTime Jan1st1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

  public static long CurrentTimeMillis
  {
   get { return (long)(DateTime.UtcNow - Jan1st1970).TotalMilliseconds; }
  },   and fix this issue.